# My Bubblesort won't sort anything, and won't let me pass by reference

Tags: c++, swap, bubble-sort

For my CS class we are making a program that reads in numbers, calculates the inflation rate from those 2 numbers, sends those numbers to an array, bubblesorts the array, and then prints that array out after it is sorted. However, I can't get my bubblesort to sort, either there is a compiler error when I use &, or there it just doesnt sort. Can anyone help? Thank you!
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
double InflationRate(float old_cpi, float new_cpi);
double inflateRate;
void getCPIValues(float &old_cpi, float &new_cpi);
float swap_values(float&i, float&j);
void bubbleSort(float a[], int number_used);
float old_cpi=-1;
float new_cpi=-1;
const int MAX_RATES=20;
float a[MAX_RATES]={};
int main()   //C++ programs start by executing the function main
{


char Continue = 'y';
double total = 0;
int i=0;
do{
     getCPIValues(old_cpi, new_cpi);
     InflationRate(old_cpi, new_cpi);
     cout<< "Inflation rate is "<<inflateRate<<endl;
     total = total+inflateRate;
     cout << "Try again? (y or Y): ";
     i++;
     a[i-1]= inflateRate;
     cin >> Continue;
}while ((Continue == 'y')||(Continue == 'Y'));

cout<<"Average rate is "<<total/i<<endl;
int number_used= i-1;
for (int p; p<=number_used; p++)
{
    cout<<a[p]<<endl;
}

return 0;
}



double InflationRate(float old_cpi, float new_cpi)
{

    inflateRate = (new_cpi - old_cpi)/old_cpi*100;
    return(inflateRate);
}
void getCPIValues(float &old_cpi, float &new_cpi)
{
    cout<<"Enter the old and new consumer price indices: ";
    cin>>old_cpi>>new_cpi;
    if ((old_cpi<=0)||(new_cpi<=0))
    {
        do
        {
        cout<<"Error: CPI values must be greater than 0";
        cin>>old_cpi>>new_cpi; 
        }while ((old_cpi<=0)||(new_cpi<=0));
    } 
}
float swap_values(float&i, float&j)
{
    int temp = i;
    i=j;
    j=temp;
    return(i, j);
}
void bubbleSort(float a[], int number_used) 
{ 
   for (int m = 0; m < number_used-1; m++)       


       for (int n = 0; n < number_used-m-1; n++)  
           if (a[n] > a[n+1]) 
              swap_values(&a[n], &a[n+1]); 
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Regarding `return (i, j);`, read up on [the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator).

Comment: `swap_values(&a[n], &a[n + 1]);` -> `swap_values(a[n], a[n + 1]);`. Don't need to take addresses when the function accepts a variable by reference. If you are passing by reference with pointers (`float swap_values(float*i, float*j)`), then you need to use `&` to get the addresses.

Comment: Yeah but when I do that, it just doesn't sort it

Comment: Different problem. In the current case, the code doesn't compile. Compiles but doesn't work is a wee bit closer to correct. Lemme take a longer walk through the code and see if I can spot what's up. In the meantime, drop your code into [whatever debugger comes with your development environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) (strongly consider getting a different environment if yours doesn't have a debugger)  and step through the sorting to see if you can spot where things go awry before I do.

Comment: The bubble sort looks good to me. All you need to do is call it.

Comment: Wow I completely forgot to call it, thanks so much